# Ruby Rspec Tests

Tags: ruby, rspec

Hi need help with this rspec test I'm trying to pass with a certain method. The problem is I dont know what its asking. Here is the test I'm trying to pass.

```
describe "repeater" do
  it "executes the default block" do
    block_was_executed = false
    repeater do
      block_was_executed = true
    end
    block_was_executed.should == true
  end

  it "executes the default block 3 times" do
    n = 0
    repeater(3) do
      n += 1
    end
    n.should == 3
  end

  it "executes the default block 10 times" do
    n = 0
    repeater(10) do
      n += 1
    end
    n.should == 10
  end
end
```

I don't really get what I need to do to make this test pass because I don't really know what its asking. If can explain in words without actually giving me the code to make it pass that would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

First: this seems like a homework assignment. Googling for one of the test names, turns up [this](https://github.com/alexch/learn_ruby/blob/master/05_silly_blocks/silly_blocks_spec.rb).

In the first test, the `repeater` method needs to take a block which is then ran so that the variable is set.

In the second test, the `repeater` method needs to take an argument and then iterate through the given block the given number of times.

The third test is the same as the second test, except it is supposed to iterate through 10 times and not 3 times.

Comment: Not a homework assignment I just wanna figure the code part out for myself.

Answer (score 1):

As Neil said, the method looks like this:

```
def repeater(n=1, &block)
  n.times &block
end
```

The method expects a number and a block, if no number is passed it will execute the block just one time.

Answer (score 0):

The test is for a method which must be called `repeater`

`repeater` should accept 0 or 1 params, and should accept a code block and yield to it

The param if provided is the number of times to yield to the code block

If no param is provided, `repeater` should yield to the code block at least once.